# SQL JOIN - learnsql EXERCISE

Tags: sql

I am trying to work on some SQL exercise and run into an error, can you help me check where I went wrong?

**Task**

Get details of all readers and their current book loans from the book_loan table. A book is considered currently loaned if the return_date column is NULL.

Display four columns:

- the reader's first name
- the reader’s last name
- the book title
- the borrow date

If a reader doesn't currently have any books on loan, show NULL for the book title and borrow date.

Data schema as in this screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMfaT.png)

Thank you very much for your help!

My code:

```
with cte as 
(
    select distinct 
        r.id as reader_id, r.first_name, r.last_name, 
        b.title, 
        l.borrow_date, l.return_date
    from 
        reader r 
    left join 
        book_loan l on l.reader_id = r.id
    left join 
        book b on l.book_id = b.id
    where 
        l.return_date is null
    order by 
        r.first_name, r.last_name
)
select 
    c.first_name, c.last_name, c.title, c.borrow_date
from 
    cte c 
right join 
    reader on reader.id = c.reader_id
```

My result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv6sW.png)

Expected result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6urS.png)

Comment: Please don’t link to images. Add all relevant information to your question as editable text, appropriately formatted. Just as a hint, there’s no need for a CTE, just join the tables using the appropriate INNER/LEFT joins

Comment: why did you join `reader` twice? its already `join`ed in `cte` but used in another `join` outside the `cte`. can't you `select ... from cte`? if you are unsure what `cte` do, try simple `join`s first, i think the problem does not require `cte` to solve.

Comment: @NickW so sorry, I was new to all this. I will add the data as text next time 
ye, I tried inner/ left, but for some reason, it only shows the book that were currently on loan, and not those that already returned the book (have value in both borrow and return date)

FriendlyDragon helped me below though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be very simple, if you just divide your query and try to investigate it step-by-step.
I prepared some exemple for you, please take a look: https://dbfiddle.uk/VV0XA4C8

I put several comment from there in this answer:

• step 01, first table

This is very simple, we just see our readers

```
select distinct 
       r.id as reader_id, 
       r.first_name, 
       r.last_name
from   reader r 
order by 
       r.first_name, 
       r.last_name
```

• step 02, connect book_loan

Nothing changes except new two fields

```
select distinct 
       r.id as reader_id, 
       r.first_name, 
       r.last_name,
       l.borrow_date, 
       l.return_date
from   reader r 
  left join book_loan l on l.reader_id = r.id
order by 
       r.first_name, 
       r.last_name
```

• step 03, apply condidion

Wrong result started from this step:

- if you have condision in WHERE clouse - it will filter your result

```
select distinct 
       r.id as reader_id, 
       r.first_name, 
       r.last_name,
       l.borrow_date, 
       l.return_date
from   reader r 
  left join book_loan l on l.reader_id = r.id
where l.return_date is null
order by 
       r.first_name, 
       r.last_name
```

• step 04, apply condidion on join

But, if you move your condition into the join clouse - it will work as expected

```
select distinct 
       r.id as reader_id, 
       r.first_name, 
       r.last_name,
       l.borrow_date, 
       l.return_date
from   reader r 
  left join book_loan l on l.reader_id = r.id and l.return_date is null
order by 
       r.first_name, 
       r.last_name
```

• step 05, get final result

Just add book title, and you do not need any additional subqueries here

```
select distinct 
       r.id as reader_id, 
       r.first_name, 
       r.last_name,
       b.title,
       l.borrow_date, 
       l.return_date
from   reader r 
  left join book_loan l on l.reader_id = r.id and l.return_date is null
  left join book b on b.id = l.book_id
order by r.id,
       r.first_name, 
       r.last_name
```

Comment: OMG, thank you so much! I cannot cast a vote yet, but you were awesome!

Answer (score 1):

you are using first and last name from table c in select query add alias to join table

```
select r.first_name, r.last_name, c.title, c.borrow_date
from cte c 
right join reader r on r.reader.id = c.reader_id
```